# Tools for map animations

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, leaflet, software-recommendations, animation

I am preparing some visualizations of data (mainly animated choropleths), and I am looking for suitable tools.
Ideally, I am looking for something similar to this kind of [animated infographics](http://videohive.net/item/infographics-3d-map-kit/4835077). So, I don't need very advanced GIS analysis, but rather graphical capabilities that allow me to add animated arrows/text/symbols/etc.
So far I checked:

- ArcMap: obviously it's very powerful, but the animations seem rather disappointingly crude.
- QGIS: same as ArcMap. Powerful tool but the results are not very sleek either.
- OpenLayers/LeafLet/d3: they are fine to render an interactive choropleth, but not to generate a complex animation.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include an example of an "animated infographics often shown in newspapers" that you are looking for, please?  If you save one as a GIF you should be able to embed it in your question like has been done [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148823).

Comment: I agree with underdark - moving the camera around and animating the choropleth part of the video you link to could be done in Arc, but the labels and lines are a whole other level that's more about graphics, animation, and video editing than GIS. Your link itself leads to such a software package, or rather a plugin for After Effects.

Comment: This type of interaction and tooling is coming fast in the industry, but is probably not available without at least some enterprise level tools.   It would be possible to animate something similar to this by extending leaflet and leveraging some of the mapbox offerings.  Although your use case would be better suited in Aftereffects.  There is also a decent write up on the topic here http://victorianece.com/2014/04/adventures-in-map-animation-with-qgis-after-effectsc4d-and-illustrator/

Answer (score 3):

Imho, what you see in http://videohive.net/item/infographics-3d-map-kit/4835077 has nothing at all to do with GIS anymore. It's an animation done by an artist and should be treated as such. You won't find a GIS which can create anything remotely this artistic. It's just not at all part of the GIS toolchain.

Comment: It's drifting away from GIS and to the side of 3D sofwares. The GIS guy/lady will limit his/her to outputing a good skin for the spherical globe.